# How can I calculate the ellipses coordinate path for an orbital animation in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, skrollr

I am using the [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) framework to animate different parts of a web page I am building.

So far it is working awesome. I highly recommend that framework. I am now investigating the feasibility of making satellite images orbit a globe icon as I scroll. My initial plan was to achieve this effect by animating the top:, left:, z-index:, scale, and opacity attributes of the satellite images as they move around the globe. This is working well.

The difficult part now is the path. How do I calculate the correct positions for each object to follow an elliptical path around the globe? Doing it by guessing was very slow and frustrating and turned out badly.

Is there an equation I should be using for this? Is there a better way than animating the top and left attributes of the image? Any thoughts or ideas would be very helpful.

Comment: Did you check out the code of this skrollr example? http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/examples/circular_motion.html There are two custom easing functions defined which use sine and cosine.

Comment: I hadn't realized that was there. Thanks for pointing that out. And thanks for the library! It is really amazing.